# Getting JSON data available to all scopes in JQuery/ javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

With JQuery, I'm loading a set of postcode data via a json call, which is loaded once on document load to populate an option select. I can do that within the one function and it's fine.

However, every time the user selects a different postcode in the select, the code is fired (via .change), and I'm required to load the (quite large) same json data again to populate some different fields.

Because the first call is contained in the callback function, the data never gets outside that scope, and can't be reused again.

If someone changes the items 100 times, that's 100 times the data gets loaded, which seems wasteful, and slow.

Is there any way to call that data once, and have it available to the global/wider scope so it's accessible to the .change function?

*EDIT* Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  GetPostcodes();
  $("#postcodes").change(function() {
    console.log("Selection Changed to " + $(this).val());
  });
});

function GetPostcodes() {
  $.getJSON("population.json", function(cases) {
      var filtercases = $(cases).filter(function(i, n) {
      return n.POA_NAME16 >= "2450" && n.POA_NAME16 <= "2489"
    });

    var postcodes = [];
    $.each(filtercases, function(i, n) {
      postcodes.push(n);
    });
    postcodes = postcodes.unique();
    postcodes = postcodes.sort();

    var options = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < postcodes.length; i++) {
      options.push('<option value="',
        postcodes[i].POA_NAME16, '">',
        postcodes[i].POA_NAME16, '</option>');
    }
    $("#postcodes").html(options.join(''));

  });
}
```

Here's what the JSON looks like:

```
 {
    "POA_NAME16": 2000,
    "Combined": "BARANGAROO,DARLING HARBOUR,,DAWES POINT,HAYMARKET,MILLERS POINT,PARLIAMENT HOUSE,SYDNEY,SYDNEY SOUTH,THE ROCKS",
    "Tot_p_p": 27411
  },
  {
    "POA_NAME16": 2006,
    "Combined": "THE UNIVERSITY OF SYDNEY",
    "Tot_p_p": 1259
  },
```

So while I'm only using the postcode data in the first call to populate the drop down box, I'd like to be able to access all the information for when the .change property is fired to show the other information.

Cheers

Comment: Why can't you store the data in a global variable the first time it is loaded? Showing us some code would be useful.

Comment: I've tried a global variable, but because it's an asynchronous call, it just jumps over and never gets defined.

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong. Show us your code in a [MRE].

Comment: Edited with the current code now, but doing it this way doesn't allow me access to that json outside that function, and if I try to return the json data from the function, it's not accessible outside it because of the async call.

Comment: Which data do you need to access? The `postcodes` array?

Comment: the json data, cases in the function - as when the .change property is fired, what I want is to use different data from that same file, depending on the postcode selected. Because I can't access that in the .change function, I have to load that json again and grab that info from there.

Comment: So create a variable _outside_ the function and assign `cases` to this variable the first time you load it. https://jsfiddle.net/zvp7jefL/

Comment: Thanks - I think I figured out where I went wrong, I'll put another reply up.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has come that I've tried to do this:

```
GetPostcodes();
console.log(the global variable I set)
```

which doesn't work.

But if I don't reference that global variable until another event, everything's in there and working - so although I already had the answer - your help pushed me to look further in. Cheers :P